# Why does the device plugin work with hostNetwork set to true

Tags: kubernetes, network-programming, openshift, grpc-go

#### Introduction

I am developing a containerized application that runs on an Openshift cluster and needs access to some host devices located under /dev. This can be achieved by adding `privileged: true` flag to container, but due to security reasons my pod shouldn't be privileged.

A workaround for that is using [device-plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/) that can mount desired devices and share them with pod using gRPC.
We end up using [squat/generic-device-plugin](https://github.com/squat/generic-device-plugin) which does exactly what we need.

Sample DaemonSet for starting the generic-device-plugin as [DaemonSet](https://github.com/squat/generic-device-plugin/blob/main/manifests/generic-device-plugin.yaml).

Official Kubernetes documentation states that device-plugins should be [deployed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/#device-plugin-deployment) as privileged, as
the canonical directory /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins/ requires privileged access.

#### Running generic-device as non-privileged

We discovered that device-plugin can work properly without privileged (`privileged: false`) when we instead set `hostNetwork: true`.

Running generic-device-plugin without privileged or hostNetwork will result in a fail with error:
`Error while dialing: dial unix /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins/kubelet.sock: connect: permission denied`.

#### Setup

Tests were performed on an Openshift v4.13 cluster installed on bare metal via assisted installer.
It runs multus CNI.

#### Question

Why does having direct access to host nodes network interfaces (`hostNetwork: true`) allows access to sockets from /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins?